# Python 3.2: Can I multiply a tuple in a list without concatenating the individual tuples into one tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.2

I like the simplicity of this list comprehension syntax,

```
waves = [(frequency, amplitude) * wave_count]
```

but in this case I don't like that it concatenates the multiplied tuple into one long tuple.

Is there a simple way to effectively multiply a tuple to become separate tuples in a list?

Thanks,

Victor

P.S.

Oh, wait! I just figured it out, but I think I'll post this question anyway since it confused me.

This did it:

```
waves = [(frequency, amplitude)] * wave_count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *real* list comprehension:

```
waves = [(frequency, amplitude) for _ in range(wave_count)]
```

or just multiply the list as you did:

```
waves = [(frequency, amplitude)] * wave_count
```

The latter is safe in this case because tuples are not mutable.

The first option creates a *new* tuple for each iteration of the loop, the second option expands the list using `wave_count` references to the *same* tuple. If you used a mutable instead (say, a list or dict), then that could lead to unexpected results, but it does use less memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there more than a semantic difference (one is 'real list comprehension' and one is apparently not) between the two examples that you offered?

Comment: @Victor: expanded to explain the difference.